# Zoomable and Panable Collection of Objects

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, core-graphics

I'm pretty new to iphone development, so this is more of a high-level question. The simplest description of what I am looking to do is create a zoomable/panable field on which I can place a bunch of circle objects. The number of these circles is likely to be in the hundreds, and ideally when the user zooms in close enough, more information can be displayed. From stuff I've read, it seems like `UIScrollView` provides the simplest way of making a zoomable/panable view but I'm not sure it's the best way to handle a view that includes a hundred graphic objects. I'm trying to figure out if I should progress further down that path or look into things like CALayers, Core Graphics, etc. Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance,

Roman

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use UIScrollView, because it will save a lot of time for handling proper zooming/scrolling. So the workflow is next:
1. Zoom you scroll view
2. In delegate's callback scrollViewDidEndZooming:withView:atScale:  you can obtain the scale and determine the level of detail that you need.
3. redraw the visible region (using Core Graphics) with appropriate level of detail (number of circles etc.)

So you should use the mix of Core Graphics and UIKit.

Comment: Thanks, that is very helpful and makes sense. Would it be relatively straightforward to detect when someone taps one of the circles?

Comment: Well it's really easy. You can obtain the touch coordinates in the view, and then iterate through your circles and determine whether point lies within one of them.